# How to set -J-Xmx parameter in PyDev Eclipise for Jython

Tags: eclipse, out-of-memory, pydev, jython-2.7

When I run the program from PyDev/Eclipse, it runs out of memory and gives the following error:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead
>   limit exceeded

It goes away when I pass the -J-Xmx2048 limit from the command line. So clearly, this can be solved if PyDev can read these somehow.

In Eclipse, I tried setting this values in the run options (in eclipse) as program & vm arugments, but I get the same error. I also tried setting the JAVA_MEM option, but that doesn't help either.

Any ideas how I can instruct PyDev/Eclipse to read these arguments?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the Run As -> Run Configurations -> Arguments -> Vm Arguments for Jython also expect Java arguments and not Jython ones :/

Setting the VM arguments to -Xmx2048 fixed the issue. The memory usage for java now peaks to 2G (earlier 1G) confirming the fix.